# WebViewClient not called the second time

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I have a `WebView` which I use to load some `html` content locally in my app. It first loads the content, then calls a `JavaScript` function which then scrolls the `WebView` to a particular position.

The following code illustrates how I do this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private WebView web1;
private int ID;
private MyWebViewClient webViewClient1;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        // Get the ID of the law to be loaded.
        ID = getIntent().getIntExtra("element_id", 1);

        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Initialize the webViewClients.
        webViewClient1 = new MyWebViewClient(true);

        web1.setWebViewClient(webViewClient1);

        displayArticle(web1);
    }

private void displayArticle (WebView wv) {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Code to build the HTML String.

String finalHtml = sb.toString();

            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/", finalHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        String urlToLoad;

        MyWebViewClient (boolean setUrlToLoad) {
            if (setUrlToLoad) {
                setUrlToLoad();
            }           
        }

        public void setUrlToLoad () {
            this.urlToLoad = "javascript:(function () {" +
                    "var elem = document.getElementById('e"+ID+"');" +
                    "var x = 0;" +
                    "var y = 0;" +
                    "while (elem != null) {" +
                    "x += elem.offsetLeft;" +
                    "y += elem.offsetTop;" +
                    "elem = elem.offsetParent;" +
                    "}" +
                    "window.scrollTo(x, y);" +
                    "})()";
        }

        @Override 
        public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.d("Pages", "Page loading started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            Log.d("Pages", "Webview content load error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.d("Pages", "Page loading finished");

            if (urlToLoad != null) {
                // Scroll to the position.
                view.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
                urlToLoad = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the callback functions in the `MyWebViewClient` class are called for the first request using `wv.loadDataWithBaseURL` in the `displayArticle(WebView wv)` function, but when the request is finished and `onPageFinished` is called, the `view.loadUrl(urlToLoad);` call does not invoke another set of callbacks from `MyWebViewClient`. I am not quite sure why since it must be the same `WebView` I originally used and it should have the same instance of `MyWebViewClient` set.

Moreover, there are other `loadUrl` calls that I make with the same `WebView`, and this behaviour persists.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

`loadUrl("javascript:...")` is a bit of a special case: it evaluates the JavaScript code in the current page's context (just like `<a href='javascript:...'>clicky</a>` would) and therefore you won't get `onPageStarted`/`onPageFinished` callbacks.

Comment: I see. So how do I know when the webView has finished processing the JavaScript code? Are there no callbacks for this case?

Comment: For scrolling knowing when it had finished executing doesn't help you, you'd need to override `WebView.onScrollChanged` (don't forget to call `super.onScrollChanged` from your override).